# Divide the files get from FSO

Tags: javascript, fso

I've here an code which gives me the amount of the files, saved in an Folder:

```
//get file amount in folder
var fileAmount = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
var folderObj = fileAmount.GetFolder("C:\\cnc\\USER");  //pfad, dann in benuzername/dokumente
// create enumerator type of  collection of files in folder  
var filesCollection = new Enumerator(folderObj.Files);  
var fileObj;  
for (filesCollection.moveFirst(); !filesCollection.atEnd(); filesCollection.moveNext()) {  
    fileObj = filesCollection.item();  
    projName = fileObj.Name;  
    alert(projName)  ; // at the Moment msg. with all file names...
}
```

And I want to Import them here in "var files":

```
var files = [
    {'name': projName + ',', 'date': ProjDate + '&nbsp; '} //date is also there but not in the code
],
insertDiv = function(openerWrapper, file){
    // create element
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        content = "",
        _key;
    for(_key in file){
        if(file.hasOwnProperty(_key)){
          content += " " + file[_key];
        }
    }

    // this is content
    div.innerHTML = content;

    // CSS class
    div.className += " metroFileBoxAuto";
    openerWrapper.appendChild(div);
};
```

The Code is working perfect, if I put more elements in 'var files' I'll get all div elements I needed, but I've to put them manually in the 'var files'. How I can put all the collected filenames in 'var files' automatically? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try something like this to populate the array with collected filenames:

```
//get file amount in folder
var fileAmount = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var folderObj = fileAmount.GetFolder("C:\\cnc\\USER");  //pfad, dann in benuzername/dokumente
// create enumerator type of  collection of files in folder
var filesCollection = new Enumerator(folderObj.Files);
var fileObj, files[], projName;
for (filesCollection.moveFirst(); !filesCollection.atEnd(); filesCollection.moveNext()) {
    fileObj = filesCollection.item();
    projName = fileObj.Name;  
    alert(projName)  ; // at the Moment msg. with all file names...
    files.push({'name': projName + ' ,', 'date': 'some_date' + '&nbsp; '});
}
```